# Is abortion of children with Down's syndrome legal in EU?

Tags: european-union, constitutional-law

In many countries of the European Union, abortions are performed on women after knowledge of down syndrome in the embryo. In some countries this disease has almost disappeared from the population. And according to MIT news in recent months, we are now on the verge of being able to detect other diseases such as some form of diabetes.

We must not forget that we can also already suppress HIV in births, even if for this virus, the probability of seeing it disappear from the population is much lower.

All this means that in a few years the countries of the European Union will be able to create populations almost disease-free at birth.

The definition of eugenics is :

> the study of or belief in the possibility of improving the qualities of the human species or a human population, especially by such means as discouraging reproduction by persons having genetic defects or presumed to have inheritable undesirable traits (negative eugenics) or encouraging reproduction by persons presumed to have inheritable desirable traits (positive eugenics).

And we already know that [article 3 of EU charter of human rights prohibit "eugenics practices".](https://fra.europa.eu/en/eu-charter/article/3-right-integrity-person)

My first question is : Why does practices are not considered as eugenics practices following EU charter of human rights ? And my second question is : If it is proven that the constitution of human rights does not prevent such abortions, does this mean that it does not prevent abortions based on the probabilities of the height or IQ of the future child either?

Answer (score 3):

It would appear the answer is "it depends", based on where the abortion takes place. It's possible that France has a domestic law that prohibits aborting children with Down's syndrome — which would make such an act illegal if performed in France. I am not familiar with French law so do not know and cannot comment on that.

More generally speaking, there is no EU-wide law that prohibits such abortions. For example, in the UK, such abortions are considered somewhat routine and there is no specific law prohibiting them. Indeed, they are explicitly permitted under the [Abortion Act 1967](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1967/87/section/1). While there is a prohibition on eugenics in the [Charter of Fundamental Rights of the European Union](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/charter/pdf/text_en.pdf) (the Charter), that would only seem to be engaged in the event some EU or domestic law was passed that mandated some form of eugenics.

[The European Convention on Human Rights](https://www.echr.coe.int/Documents/Convention_ENG.pdf) has Article 2—the "Right to Life"—however, the rights established by this Article typically only apply to living beings and have not yet been held to firmly apply to foetuses (*Vo v. France [2004]* ECtHR, para 80.) and an unborn child can be held not to possess these rights until the moment of birth (*Paton v. British Pregnancy Advisory Service Trustees [1979]*) although it varies from Member State to Member State.

Some Member States (e.g. Ireland) constitutionally guarantee unborn children the right to live, in which case such abortions would presumably be illegal, but unless there's a specific law that prohibits such abortions, in almost all Member States of the European Union, such abortions would not be illegal.

In conclusion, are such abortions prohibited in the EU? Not as far as my research suggests.

Comment: If these rights only apply to living beings, it means that these laws are completely useless because when you are born it's already considered as murder. In the statement "the prohibition of eugenic practices, in particular those aiming at the selection of persons", what do you think the writers talk about "persons" ?

Comment: A "person" in the eyes of the law is a living person — an unborn child is not, generally, a "person" until they are born. At the moment, these sorts of abortions are not held to conflict with the Charter or the European Convention on Human Rights precisely because it's considered only a living person can exercise these rights and protections.

It would be eugenics (and thus prohibited under the Charter) to prevent someone with Down's syndrome from procreating, but not to prevent them from being born in the first place.

Comment: I would imagine the writers chose the word "person" to avoid having to enumerate "adults and children" each time, but perhaps also to root the essence of humanity in the text given these sentiments came about shortly after the conclusion of the Second World War.

Comment: I completly agree with you and I think you are right, but I still find this strange. Because in the next year we will be able to detect a lot of disabilities like diabetes and some traits like height or IQ and I think that even if they are not born yet, it's still "must" be considered as eugenics practice because making only babies tall, clever and without disease really looks like eugenics practice. But yes it's not really "person" so law don't apply to them.

Comment: Of course. It is a shortfalling of existing law that unborn children aren't covered by this. To the average person on the street it's eugenics but not according to law. I think the law should change, and hopefully it will in the future.

Comment: I don't agree with you on the "average people" point because all people I know don't considered abortion of down syndrome foetus as eugenics, they considered it's not eugenics because it doesn't make them more clever or more powerfull. But I don't agree with them. If the law change, this kind of abortion will no longer be possible and I don't think people would enjoy it. In France majority are against eugenics and majority wants abortion for sown syndrome at the same time. It's really complex. I have no idea what we should do.

Comment: Can this in effect lead to a situation where an abortion would be legal if the child didn't have Down's syndrome, and illegal otherwise, if all other circumstances were exactly the same?

Comment: @vsz Not unless the EU or a Member State's domestic legislature pass a law outlawing such abortions on grounds of eugenics (which in itself would face an automatic human right challenge) or the ECtHR recognises the rights in the Charter apply directly to unborn children, but that in itself is a delicate balancing act against the rights of the mother.

Comment: @Matthew That's not within the purview of the ECtHR, but would be in the purview of the ECJ ([see Wikipedia article on difference between the two courts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationship_between_the_European_Court_of_Justice_and_European_Court_of_Human_Rights))

Comment: @DPenner1 Yes, sorry. I was mixing up the Charter with the Convention.

Comment: Also, I just read the *[Vo v. France](https://www.globalhealthrights.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/ECtHR-2004-Vo-v-France.pdf)* case you cite. Putting aside that the ECtHR doesn't adjudicate the Charter, could you explain how the case supports that "these rights typically only apply to living beings and an unborn child is generally held not to possess these rights until the moment of birth" ?  I'm just not reading that anywhere in the decision (the court appears to explicitly sidestep that question in paragraph 85).

Comment: Para 80 of the judgment supports that Article 2 only applies to living beings since the Court asserts that the foetus is not a "person", and it flows that, because dead people can't enforce their Convention rights, "person" can only refer to a "living being". I feel like I should have used a different word than "living being", but I'm not sure what.

I split the "an unborn child is generally held not to possess these rights until the moment of birth" into a separate citation because the case only references that assertion, it doesn't support it directly and is not universally applicable.